# Differential equation of Rabbit Fox Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry

A rabbit is hiding at $(0,1)$ and a fox is standing at the point $(0,-1)$ and a big tree is at $(0,0)$ so that rabbit is safe from the attack of Fox.

Now the Fox moves in horizontal direction at a speed of $1$ unit along the line $y=-1$ towards negative infinity from $(0,-1)$ .

To avoid Detection, rabbit will run towards its right but in a curved path at a constant speed of $2$ units so as to keep Tree between itself and Fox.

Form the Differential equation of the path of Rabbit.

My try:

Let any point on the path of rabbit be $P(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$

Also any point on path of Fox is $Q(a,-1)$

according to my thinking the points $P$,$O$ and $Q$ are always collinear.

So

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 &1 \\ 
a & - 1&1 \\ 
 r \cos \theta&r \sin \theta  & 1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

which gives $$a=-\cot \theta$$

So the point $Q$ is $Q(-\cot \theta, -1)$

any clue from here?

Comment: (0,1) is not on the negative x-axis, so it doesn't make any sense to say "the Fox moves in horizontal direction at a speed of 1 unit along negative x-axis from (0,1)."

Comment: ok i edited accordingly

Comment: The points $(1,0)-"Rabit"$, $(0,0)-"Tree"$ and $(0,1)-"Fox"$ are not aligned.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't get it. The rabbit is *not* in the line of sight of the fox at the beginning. Then the fox moves away from the rabbit, and so does the rabbit from the fox. The only way to make sense of the problem is to make the tree not a point

Comment: @all i am extremely sorry ,now i have modified the question with proper details

Answer (score 1):

The movement is described by

$$
\dot x^2+\dot y^2 = v_r^2\\
\frac{x}{y} =  \frac{-v_f t}{-1}
$$

here $v_r = 2,\ \ v_f = 1$

Attached the rabbit evasion curve in green

[image]

In dashed red the opposition at $t = 0.5$

The MATHEMATICA script

`parms = {vf -> 1, vr -> 2};
equs = {x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 == vr^2, x'[t] == D[y[t] vf t, t]} /. parms
tmax = 1;
soly = NDSolve[{equs, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}][[2]];
gr1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. soly], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[{-t, -1}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
p1 = Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. soly] /. {t -> 0.5};
p2 = {-1 t, -1} /. {t -> 0.5};
p0 = {0, 0};
grp1 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[p1, 0.02]}];
grp2 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[p2, 0.02]}];
grp0 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[p0, 0.02]}];
grp3 = ListLinePlot[{p1, p2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
Show[gr1, gr2, grp1, grp2, grp3, grp0, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`